# How to send AWS SNS notification from JavaScript lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to JS trying to send SNS notification from my lambda function. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong here;

code:

```
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const { writeFileSync, unlinkSync } = require("fs");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const sns = new AWS.SNS();

const SNS_TOPIC_ARN = 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:96xxxxxxxxxx:test-cost-lambda';

module.exports.virusScan = async (event, context) => {
  if (!event.Records) {
    console.log("Not an S3 event invocation!");
    return;
  }

  for (const record of event.Records) {
    if (!record.s3) {
      console.log("Not an S3 Record!");
      continue;
    }
    
    const key = decodeURIComponent(record.s3.object.key.replace(/\+g/, " "));

    console.log('getting the file', key, record);

    // get the file
    const s3Object = await s3
      .getObject({
        Bucket: record.s3.bucket.name,
        Key: record.s3.object.key,
      })
      .promise();
      
    console.log('got the file', record.s3.object.key);

    // write file to disk
    writeFileSync(`/tmp/${record.s3.object.key}`, s3Object.Body);

    console.log('wrote the file');
    
    try {
      // scan it
      execSync(`./bin/clamscan --database=./var/lib/clamav /tmp/${record.s3.object.key}`);

      console.log('updating tag to clean');

      await s3
        .putObjectTagging({
          Bucket: record.s3.bucket.name,
          Key: record.s3.object.key,
          Tagging: {
            TagSet: [
              {
                Key: 'av-status',
                Value: 'clean'
              }
            ]
          }
        })
        .promise();

      console.log('updated tag to clean');
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('err', err);
      if (err.status === 1) {
        // tag as dirty, AND send SNS notification
        await s3
          .putObjectTagging({
            Bucket: record.s3.bucket.name,
            Key: record.s3.object.key,
            Tagging: {
              TagSet: [
                {
                  Key: 'av-status',
                  Value: 'dirty'
                }
              ]
            }
          })
          .promise();
        
        // send SNS notification
        await sns
          .publish({
            TopicArn: SNS_TOPIC_ARN,
            Message: `Object ${record.s3.object.key} in bucket ${record.s3.bucket.name} has been tagged as dirty.`
          })
          .promise();
      }
    }

    // delete the temp file
    unlinkSync(`/tmp/${record.s3.object.key}`);
  }
};
```

Basically above written lambda code scans objects in s3 bucket, then tag the objects clean/dirty.

I want to send a SNS notification whenever a AWS S3 Bucket object is tagged "dirty". The tagging functionality is working fine, but it is not sending SNS notification as I was expecting it to.

Comment: Firstly, does lambda function has enough permission?

Comment: yes it does have the permission for SNS.